# How to Find Different Phone Digit Patterns Using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to be able to determine a pattern within a phone number using regular expression. I need to find how to check if string has a group of same digits next to each other.

**Example** 
if have following phone number and 3 patterns. 
suppose : x = 1 , y = 2 , z = 3

Phone = 794444444
pattern one finds: 79xxxxxxx
pattern two finds : 79xyyyyyy
pattern three finds : 79xyyyxxx

if the number matches pattern one, then the category is Platinum
if the number matches pattern two, then the category is Golded
if the number matches pattern three, then the category is Silver

Comment: Are you looking for help with the regular expressions or with how to check if a existing regular expression matches? (For the latter use [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7)).

Comment: i just what to know how to write its expression or if there is any other way to do it

Comment: Is your x,y,z were constants?

Comment: no they are not constants, they just change for each msisdn like variables

Comment: in my example the phone number is 794444444 which matches the pattern one,the number could be 795666555 which matches the pattern three. i just want to know how to find the the pattern matches the phone number or vise versa

Comment: if `x=4` `y=5` `z=6`.The pattern 1 will be `794{7}`,pattern 2 `7945{6}`,pattern3 `7945{3}4{3}` .you have to change the 4,5,6 according to x,y,z

Comment: you are perfect man. how about this pattern : 79xyzyzyz<br> x = 4 , y = 0 , x = 8

Comment: `794(08){3}` It matches `794` and repeating pattern `yz` three times.You can solve these on own.Try basics, https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Comment: this is really appreciated. just one more thing please. lets suppose X is a variable between 0-9, how can i put it in the pattern ?

Comment: string str = "792222222";
            bool match = Regex.IsMatch(str, @"79[1-9]{7}"); this is what i have done but not working

Comment: @mostafahakimi Do you mean to search for identical consecutive digits? [`Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^79([0-9])\1{6}$")`](https://regex101.com/r/6hqu8j/1)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create an expression which uses named capture groups in an *or* `|` statement between them and then check each individually for success.

Here is an example (*using US phone numbers of 10 digits*) of *Platinum* and *Gold* and *Silver*. I am not using your request because your text wasn't clear about what Z means, `z = 3`*. Even so, this should give you enough to finish with your actual needs.

---

**US Phone Example**
So Platinum for the example is (area code) XXX-XXXX. Gold is (area code) XYY-YYYY. While Silver is a default of any phone number as long as its 10 digits.

```
var pattern = 
@"(?<Platinum>\d\d\d(\d)\1{6,6})|(?<Gold>\d\d\d\d(\d)\2{5,5})|(?<Silver>\d{10,10})";

var mt = Regex.Match("3035444444", pattern);

mt.Groups["Platinum"].Success; // false
mt.Groups["Gold"].Success;     // true
mt.Groups["Silver"].Success;   // false
```